# Unfamiliar character when copy pasting from PDF file

Tags: replace

I am copy pasting a big chunk of code from an article in PDF format. The issue is that the operation is replacing every `*` character (the multiply operator in Fortran) by some sort of slash character, which isn't the generic slach character in Vim (used for division in Fortran).

For example, consider the expressions:

```
s2 = exp(-w * t)
s3 = 1.0_wp / s2
```

When copy pasting, I get the following:

[image]

As you can see, the regular slash is highlighted in yellow while the asterisk character was changed to some other kind of slash. I could very well go over every character and replace them, but that's not very reliable and would take quite a while (few thousand lines of code...). Ideally, I'd like to change them all in the following manner:

```
%s/[wierd-slash]/\*/g
```

I've found how to search and replace unprintable characters. `ga` or `:ascii` prints the hexa/octa value of the character under the cursor (in my case hexa 2044). However, when running `:%s/\%x2044/\*/g`, I can the error `Err: pattern not found: \%x2044`.

Also, I've tried typing `*` when the character is under the cursor (then I could search and replace last searched character) but it searched for the next word instead. In the example above, it would search for `t` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excerpt from [`:help /\%x`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2f%5c%25x) (emphasis mine):

> \%x2a       Matches the character specified with up to **two** hexadecimal characters.
>   \%u20AC  Matches the character specified with up to **four** hexadecimal
>       characters.

So you need to use `\%u2044`, rather than `\%x2044`, which will search for `<Space>44`.

You can also copy-paste it to the commandline or type `<C-v>u2044` in the commandline to get a literal `⁄`; you don't *need* to escape it with `\%u` to use it in the `:s` command (or most other commands).

Finally, I find [unicode.vim](https://github.com/chrisbra/unicode.vim) a very useful plugin. Using `:UnicodeName` on the character gives:

```
'⁄' U+2044 Dec:8260 FRACTION SLASH (/f) &frasl; /\%u2044
```

Note how this includes the `/\%u2044` ready for copy/pasting :-)

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt your plugin is *wonderful*.    I cut and paste pdf abstracts all the time, which results every time in a lot of hateful unicodes, for left and right quotes.  Problem evaporated!  Wasn't obvious to a novice like me how to install the plugin, but this [site](https://howchoo.com/g/ztmyntqzntm/how-to-install-vim-plugins-without-a-plugin-manager) was very helpful